# How would I run a batch program from another batch program within its own environment?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, batch-processing

I need to run a batch file located in another folder that must be called from another batch file.

Whenever I do call this batch file from the first, let's call them Batch_A and Batch_B, respectively, the second tries to run from the directory of the first batch file.

Batch_A needs to `call` or `start` Batch_B, however Batch_B needs to run as if I were to manually double-click it myself.

This is what I currently have at the end of my first batch

> `start "A thing" "%output%\thing.bat" /b`

Comment: You have to include /D pathToDir in start parameters, if you want to chage the working directory.

Comment: Thanks! However my working directory is dynamic, and I need the second batch file to start from its current location.

Comment: Right. So you call "start "wintitle" %dynamicDirPath% executable.bat".

Comment: I don't understand. :(
I mean, that's essentially what I've been trying.
Note my example: `start %output%\thing.bat` - which is being called at the end of my first batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into push or pop.

Before calling the second batch file, enter the "push" command:

pushd %dynamicdirectory%
Call batchfileb.bat
popd

Comment: Oh, ok. This worked. I used the `pushd` command to change the working directory to the new directory, and the second batch file is working beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If Batch_B is designed/written to be always run from the direcory where it is located
you might also consider to modify Batch_B.bat

```
setlocal
cd /D %0\..

REM your original content

endlocal
```

In %0 the path to the batchfile is stored.

The trick is to assume %0 is a directory then to change one level lower
based on that diretory.
With /D also the drive letter is changed correctly.

The cd command doesn't care if %0 is really a directory.
In fact %d doesn't even have to exist (%0\dummy\..\.. would also work).

The setlocal command is to have the working directory beeing restored
when Batch_B.bat has finished.

I noticed that the endlocal command is not really necessary
in this context since it is applied imlicitely when Batch_B finishes.